# rc1-update2 (CS0433) SecureString

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, dnx, asp.net5

I am getting this error after the last visual studio update for rc1-update2, now everything is messed up with me

The error I am getting

> Error CS0433  The type 'SecureString' exists in both
>   'System.Security.SecureString, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' and 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'

the dnvm list

> Active Version           Runtime Architecture OperatingSystem Alias
>   ------ -------           ------- ------------ --------------- -----
>
> ```
>    1.0.0-rc1-final   clr     x86          win   *    1.0.0-rc1-update1 clr     x64          win             default
> ```

Apparently I am using

> dnvm use 1.0.0-rc1-update1 -r clr -arch x64 -p

I am not using global.json and I am not intending to my project json is something like this

> {
>
> "buildOptions": {
>       "emitEntryPoint": true   },
>
> "dependencies": {
>       "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
>       "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
>       "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
>       "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
>       "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
>       "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
>       "Microsoft.Extensions.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
>       "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileProviderExtensions": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
>       "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
>       "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
>       "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
>       "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
>       "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
>       "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-rc1-final",
>       "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ViewFeatures": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
>       "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
>       "Microsoft.AspNet.Localization": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
>       "System.Security.SecureString": "4.0.0-beta-23409",
>       "System.Runtime": "4.0.21-beta-23516",
>       "System.Runtime.InteropServices": "4.0.21-beta-23516",
>       "Newtonsoft.Json": "8.0.3",
>       "Microsoft.AspNet.Http": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
>       "Microsoft.AspNet.Session": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
>       "Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
>       "System.Net.Primitives": "4.0.11-beta-23516"   },
>
> "commands": {
>       "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel",
>       "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"   },
>
> "frameworks": {
>       "dnx451": {
>         "dependencies": {       .....
>         }
>       }   },
>
> "exclude": [
>       "wwwroot",
>       "node_modules"   ],   "publishExclude": [
>       "**.user",
>       "**.vspscc"   ] }

my head had been hitting the wall for quite a while now if anybody had similar issue would be gr8 to share